# long int or double in python

Tags: double, long-integer, python-3.4

How can I convert m and n to long int or double in Python 3.4? Currently for large integers (ex:65535), the output is 'None'?

```
m = eval(input("Enter value for m: "))
n = eval(input("Enter value for n: "))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> float("1234.56")
1234.56
>>> int("1234")
1234
>>> long("12345678910")
12345678910
```

The `float()` and `int()` operators will be sufficient, as Python floats are usually the equivalent of C doubles, and if the integer is too large, `int()` will cast it to a long int. However, the `long()` operator will work if you want to explicitly cast to a long.

[Python Numeric Types Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesnumeric) for more info.

The `eval()` function is not a type casting operator, but rather evaluates strings or code objects as Python code, which can lead to problems if you're not careful:

```
>>> eval("1+2")
2
```

Answer (score 0):

[`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) returns a string, which when evaluated returns `None`. If you're trying to assign an integer value to your variables, use the [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) function:

```
m = int(input("Enter value for m: "))
n = int(input("Enter value for n: "))
```

Also, using `eval` is almost always a bad idea, as it runs the input as Python code, with the permissions of the script. If you must translate input, consider using [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) instead.